# jQuery validation plug-in help needed in asp.net 4.0 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-4.0, jquery-validate

I an using jQuery validation plugin in asp.net 4.0 application.

[**Click here to see plugin**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

I have two button on page 1)Submit 2)Cancel

When i click on Submit button this validate the form and show appropriate error message.

I used Cancel button to go back to previous page.

But now when i click on Cancel button it also show the error message.

I don't want to validate the form on Cancel button click.

How can we do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I would assume that your "Cancel" button is also `input[type=submit]`. Change it to `input[type=button]` instead, then handle it appropriately.

For example, your "Submit" button may look like this:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
       // do other stuff for a valid form
     form.submit();
   }
});
```

Whereas, your "Cancel" button is like:

```
$("#cancel").click(function() {
     history.back(); // or window.location.href = ...your link
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing markup, I'm assuming your Cancel button is actually another submit button, and you handle the redirect in the code-behind. If this is true, clicking the cancel button will also trigger the validation plugin, since it's listening for the `onsubmit` event. You have two options off the top of my head:

1. Use a hyperlink rather than a button/input element. You'll have to either
   hard-code the URL, or set it in the code-behind during page load.
2. Set the `UseSubmitBehavior` to false on your `.aspx` page, which should
   change the markup to something other than `<input type="submit" />`.